# Android : getParams() called two times dont know why?

Tags: java, android, json

Here `getParams()` method called two times and added two times data at my server. I have also noticed that my logs print twice in logcat. It occurs when I check two checkbox of from contact picker list view to send data to server.

Here is my json data :

```
{
    "send_data":[{
    "gcm_reg_id":
    "APA91bFPfAvEL_UJRHiOSohkekTh7M9qj1Kj307kFqmWh4VS8Re1aeejWSKXQnJb7q3OIjykCccbbI-0pn14DwvyjjL4ynQTHNR-m1p3vxLKy7ujGXv2MpIe0fhT2vcTJE0SW0uTjkD9iPJz0pw3sMuGojA4yxw0zg", "receiver_id":
    "170"
    },{
    "gcm_reg_id":
    "APA91bFheDJdBe3LwBk7MNchLitnKkECgVARxopr0HnFemo1vfW3Q0Mt1m6GXxccoq-wjUwoV-yXOVvcw9JwXcOZwAPyal9ZqMoA-U3fLNdaMa7pu8f-GYSyMsv16XKkgzPpzOPPKs8pc9C-7K1MhZXKgRf67DiXTSRY67swIOGP1XmJyoa3l1s", "receiver_id":
    "166"
    }]
}
```

Here is my code :

```
public class ContacsPicker extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener{
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    String phoneNumber ;
    String conatct_num;
    ArrayList<integer> status;
    ImageView iv;
    ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo> list;
    JSONArray contact_noArray;
    ArrayList<String> contact_database;
    ArrayList<String> contact_userid;
    ArrayList<String> image;
    ListView list_view;
    CustomListViewAdapter adpter;
    String user_id,message,level,time,image_name,receiver_id,regId,mail;
    Bitmap send_image;
    Store_pref obj_Store_pref;
    RegisterUser obj_RegisterUser;
    ProgressDialog Dialog;
    EditText edt_search;
    ImageView iv_search;
    RelativeLayout relative_search;
    Boolean is_serch=false;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    send_data obj_Send_data;
    String sender_regid,ba1, data;
    Context mContext;
    public Uri targetUri;
    JSONObject obj;
    Button button1_send;
    ArrayList<String> checkedValue;
    ArrayList<send_data> id_arrArrayList;


    List<com.waycreon.picture_puzzle.model.RegisterUser.Registure_user> Registure_user;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts_picker);

        mContext=this;
        edt_search =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_search);
        iv_search=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_search);
        button1_send=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1_send);
        button1_send.setOnClickListener(this);

        relative_search=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_search);
        set_invisible_relative_search();
        obj_Store_pref=new Store_pref(ContacsPicker.this);

        regId=obj_Store_pref.get_GCMreg_id();
        mail=obj_Store_pref.get_mail_id();
        Log.i("GCM reg id in contact picker class", "++++"+regId);
        Log.i("mail id in contact picker class", "++++"+mail);


        iv_search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(!is_serch)
                {
                    is_serch=true;
                    search_click();
                }
                else
                {
                    is_serch=false;
                    close_click();
                }
            }
        });


        list_view=getListView();

        message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
        level   = getIntent().getStringExtra("level");
        time     = getIntent().getStringExtra("time");
        targetUri= (Uri) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("targetUri");

        Log.i("get message", message);
        Log.i("get level", level);
        Log.i("get time", time);
        Log.i("get send_image", send_image+"=");
        Log.i("target uri", ""+targetUri);

        try {

            int orientation = getOrientation(this, targetUri);
            Log.i("orientation on create", "++"+orientation);
            matrix.postRotate(orientation);
            send_image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), targetUri);
            send_image= get_Resized_Bitmap(send_image,600,800);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            send_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
            byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
            ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba,1);
            Log.i("base 64", ba1);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        status=new ArrayList<integer>();
        contact_database=new ArrayList<String>();
        contact_userid=new ArrayList<String>();
        image=new ArrayList<String>();
        cd=new ConnectionDetector(this);
        obj_Store_pref= new Store_pref(this);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(ContacsPicker.this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);


        list = getAllPhoneContacts();

        get_registered_no();

        edt_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_search);

        edt_search .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = edt_search .getText().toString()
                        .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adpter.filter(text);
                list_view.setAdapter(adpter);
                adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                          int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });



        id_arrArrayList=new ArrayList<send_data>();
        list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {


                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) arg1.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1_check);
                cb.performClick();


                receiver_id =arg1.getTag().toString();

                //              String gcm_reg_id=Registure_user.get(arg2).gcm_regid;
                //              Log.i("gcm_reg id on list click", gcm_reg_id);

                Log.i("in if", receiver_id+"++++");

                if(!arg1.getTag().equals("0"))
                {

                    String[] separated = arg1.getTag().toString().split(" ");
                    String receiver_id =separated[0];
                    String gcm_reg_id=separated[1];



                    if (cb.isChecked()) {
                        Log.i("in if check box", receiver_id+"++++");

                        obj_Send_data = new send_data();
                        obj_Send_data.setReceiver_id(receiver_id);
                        obj_Send_data.setGcm_reg_id(gcm_reg_id);
                        id_arrArrayList.add(obj_Send_data);
                        Log.i("arraylist in if lisze", "++"+ id_arrArrayList.size());

                    } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {

                        id_arrArrayList.remove(obj_Send_data);
                        Log.i("arraylist in else lisze", "++"+ id_arrArrayList.size());

                    }
                }

                //                  if(!arg1.getTag().equals("0"))
                //                  {
                //                      receiver_id =arg1.getTag().toString();
                //                      show_alert_invitation("Invitation","Are you sure you want to send puzzle to your friend ?");
                //                      
                //                      Log.i("in if ", receiver_id+"++++");
                //                      
                //                      Get_receiver_reg_id();
                //                      
                //                      
                //                  }
                //                  else
                //                  {
                //                      show_alert_unregister_user("Notification",getString(R.string.unregister_user_message));
                //                  }
            }
        });![enter image description here][1]

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==button1_send)
        {

            //          Log.i("array list", receiver_id);
            //          Send_data();
            show_alert_invitation("Invitation","Are you sure you want to send task to your friend ?");

        }
    }


    private void get_registered_no() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (cd.isConnectingToInternet())
        {
            dialog.show();
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ContacsPicker.this);

            String url="http://karmamobichamps.com/Restaurant_app/puzzle/puzzle_app_services.php?do=get_registered_no";
            Log.i("url", url+"+++++++++++");

            StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Method.GET,url,
                    Get_Event_list_ReqSuccessListener(),
                    Get_Event_list_ReqErrorListener());
            queue.add(myReq);
        }
        else
        {
            cd.show_alert("no connection", "Please check with your internet Connection");
        }
    }

    private ErrorListener Get_Event_list_ReqErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Log.i("Volly err", error.getLocalizedMessage()+"++++");
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }

    private Listener<String> Get_Event_list_ReqSuccessListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<String>() {

            public void onResponse(String response) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Log.i("registration data", response+"");
                try {
                    JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(response);
                    if(jo.getString("ResponseCode").equals("1"))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                            obj_RegisterUser= gson.fromJson(response, RegisterUser.class);
                            Registure_user=obj_RegisterUser.Registure_user;
                            Log.i("user size", Registure_user.size()+"--");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
                {
                    image.add("0");
                }
                for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<Registure_user.size();j++)
                    {
                        String[] separated = Registure_user.get(j).mobile_no.split(" ");
                        String mobilenono = separated[separated.length-1];

                        String country_code = separated[0];
                        // String mobilenono=separated[1];
                        String mobile_no=country_code+mobilenono;

                        if(list.get(i).getcontactNumber().equals(mobilenono) || list.get(i).getcontactNumber().equals(mobile_no) ||(list.get(i).getcontactNumber().equals(Registure_user.get(j).mobile_no)) ||list.get(i).getcontactNumber().equals("0"+mobilenono)) {
                            image.set(i,Registure_user.get(j).id.toString()+" "+Registure_user.get(j).gcm_regid.toString());
                            Log.i("match", list.get(i).getcontactNumber()+"==");


                        }
                    }
                }
                adpter=new CustomListViewAdapter(ContacsPicker.this, list,Registure_user,image);
                list_view.setAdapter(adpter);
            }
        };
    }

    private void Send_data() {

        data=Write_json();
        Log.i("in send data method", data);
        Dialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        Dialog.setTitle("sending..");
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);

        Dialog.show();

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ContacsPicker.this);

        String url = null;

        url = "http://karmamobichamps.com/Restaurant_app/puzzle/send_multi_data.php" ;

        StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,url,
                send_data_ReqSuccessListener(),
                send_data_ReqErrorListener())
        {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


                //              HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //              {
                **params.put("data", data);
                params.put("image", ba1);
                params.put("sender_id", obj_Store_pref.get_user_id());
                params.put("message", message);
                params.put("level",level);
                params.put("time", time);
                params.put("status", "1");

                Log.i("data in params", data);
                Log.i("sender_id in params", obj_Store_pref.get_user_id());
                Log.i("level",level);
                Log.i("message in params", message);
                Log.i("time in params", time);
                Log.i("status in params", "1");**



                return params;
            };
        };





        queue.add(myReq);
    }

    private ErrorListener send_data_ReqErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Dialog.dismiss();
                Log.i("Volly err", error.getLocalizedMessage()+"++++");
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }

    private Listener<String> send_data_ReqSuccessListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<String>() {

            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Dialog.dismiss();
                Log.i("registration data", response+"");

                try {
                    JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(response);
                    if (jo.getString("ResponseCode").equals("1")) {
                        finish();
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }


    private void send_to_web() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final String URL = "http://karmamobichamps.com/Restaurant_app/puzzle/send_multi_data.php";
        // Post params to be sent to the server
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("data", data);
        //      params.put("image", ba1);
        //      params.put("sender_id", obj_Store_pref.get_user_id());
        //      params.put("message", message);
        //      params.put("level",level);
        //      params.put("time", time);
        //      params.put("status", "1");

        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }


                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }



    private void show_alert_invitation(String title,String msg) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        //              new ImageUpload().execute();
                        Send_data();
                        //              send_to_web();
                        Log.i("bitmap width in contact picker", ""+send_image.getWidth());
                        Log.i("bitmap height in contact picker", ""+send_image.getHeight());
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private void show_alert_unregister_user(String title,String msg) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        i.setType("text/plain");
                        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Swapatask");
                        String sAux = "\nHeyy use this amazing application i m using too...\n\n";
                        sAux = sAux + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waycreon.picture_puzzle \n\n";
                        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "choose one"));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private void set_visible_relative_search() {
        relative_search.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void set_invisible_relative_search() {
        relative_search.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
    }

    private void search_click() {
        iv_search.setImageResource(R.drawable.close);
        set_visible_relative_search();
        edt_search.setFocusable(true);
    }

    private void close_click() {
        iv_search.setImageResource(R.drawable.search_button);
        set_invisible_relative_search();
        edt_search.setText("");
    }
    /*============================get local to phone all contect===================================*/
    public ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo> getAllPhoneContacts() {
        Log.d("START","Getting all Contacts");
        ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo> arrContacts = new ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo>();
        PhoneContactInfo phoneContactInfo=null;
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID}, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false)
        {
            String contactNumber= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String contactName =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            int phoneContactID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));

            if (contactNumber.length()>0)
            {
                phoneContactInfo = new PhoneContactInfo();
                phoneContactInfo.setphoneContactID(phoneContactID);
                phoneContactInfo.setcontactName(contactName);
                phoneContactInfo.setcontactNumber(contactNumber.replaceAll("\\s+",""));
                arrContacts.add(phoneContactInfo);
            }
            phoneContactInfo = null;
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        cursor = null;
        Log.d("END","Got all Contacts");
        return arrContacts;
    }


    private void Send_push() {
        //          Dialog.show();

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ContacsPicker.this);

        String url = null;
        try {
            url = "http://karmamobichamps.com/Restaurant_app/puzzle/puzzle_app_services.php?do=Receive_Push_notification&gcm_regid="
                    +sender_regid+"&message="+URLEncoder.encode("You Have Received Swapatask Request", "UTF-8");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("rgister url", url);



        StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Method.GET,url,
                Registration_ReqSuccessListener(),
                Registration_ReqErrorListener());

        queue.add(myReq);
    }

    private ErrorListener Registration_ReqErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //                  Dialog.dismiss();
                Log.i("Volly err", error.getLocalizedMessage()+"++++");
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }

    private Listener<String> Registration_ReqSuccessListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<String>() {

            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //                  Dialog.dismiss();
                Log.i("registration data", response+"");

                //                       
            }
        };

    }


    public Bitmap get_Resized_Bitmap(Bitmap bmp, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
        int width = bmp.getWidth();
        int height = bmp.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION


        //              Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        //              matrix.postRotate(90);
        // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

        return newBitmap ;
    }

    public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
            /* it's on the external media. */
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
            return -1;
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    }

    private String Write_json() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("arraylist lisze in next button", "++"+ id_arrArrayList.size());

        obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray list1 = new JSONArray();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < id_arrArrayList.size(); i++) {

                String gcm_reg_id=Registure_user.get(i).gcm_regid;
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("receiver_id", id_arrArrayList.get(i).getReceiver_id());
                jsonObject.put("gcm_reg_id", id_arrArrayList.get(i).getGcm_reg_id());

                Log.i("gcm_reg_id", gcm_reg_id);
                list1.put(jsonObject);
            }
            obj.put("send_data", list1);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj.toString();
    }



    //  public class ImageUpload extends AsyncTask<String, String,String>
    //    {
    //        Bitmap bitmap;
    //        public ImageUpload() 
    //        {
    //            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    ////            this.bitmap=bitmap;
    //        }
    //        @Override
    //        protected void onPreExecute() 
    //        {
    //          dialog.show();
    //            super.onPreExecute();
    //          
    //        }
    //        @Override
    //        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    //        {
    //            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //            try
    //            {   
    ////            ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ////            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
    ////            byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    ////            String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba,1);
    //            Log.i("base 64", ba1);
    //            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new enter code hereArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    //            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://karmamobichamps.com/Restaurant_app/puzzle/send_multi_data.php");
    //           Log.i("url", ""+httppost);
    //            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data));
    //            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", ba1));
    //            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sende
```

[image]

Comment: You could try running with a debugger, with a breakpoint at the beginning of `getParams` and checking the stack each time that breakpoint is reached.

Comment: Thanks you for giving replay i am trying this. :)

Comment: Still not get any clue  :(

Comment: So what happened when you ran with the debugger?  Were you able to look at the stack each time?

Comment: yes. i am able to look at stack each time.

Comment: So, the stack trace would have told you where the call to `getParams` was happening.  Was it from two different places in the code?

Comment: no it comes only from one. :(

Comment: Well, maybe you can show us?  Tell us what's on the stack, rather than expecting everyone to guess.  And don't forget to indicate which lines of your code it's actually referencing.  Sorry, it's just that you've posted far too much code for me to be able to read through and see the error, and telling me that you can see what's on the stack isn't anywhere near as useful as telling me what it is that you see.

Comment: please contact me at sk@ype : angelina.rosylove i am unable to explain here

Comment: OK, I'll do that later.  I can't right now - I'm at work.

Comment: Okay i will wait for you.

Answer (score 0):

To identify the root of this issue you'll need to debug and see what's the path in which getParams is called.

You could either breakpoint within getParams block or print the stack trace to log like so:

`Throwable throwable = new IllegalArgumentException("Something");
throwable.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Thanks you for giving replay i am trying this. :)

Comment: Not get any clue  :( please help:

Answer (score 0):

Add this before adding request to request queue

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
               0,
               DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
               DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```